# What is the voltage induced on the outer shield/sheath by the current of the inner phase conductor in a concentric cable?

Tags: voltage

What is the voltage induced on the outer shield/sheath by the current of the inner phase conductor in a concentric cable?

The radius of the inner phase conductor is r, the distance from the center of the phase conductor to the shield/sheath is d, and the inner space is air.

Also, not three-phase, only single-phase.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing the current in balance between the inner and outer conductors: no "common mode" current. In that case, ideally the cable acts from an external point of view as if there is no current at all. No current, no external electric or magnetic field.

Of course a real cable has resistance and other non-idealities that produce leaks. Also, in general, the currents are not in balance.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help.